# Could not find the preLaunchTask 'npm'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a simple Hello World console application using VS Code. Following is what I have in my program.cs which I have created

```
using system;

namespace MySpace
{
 public static class MyClass
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
 }    
}
```

When I hit F5, it says "Could not find the preLaunchTask 'npm'."
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Do you have npm installed at all? You can use the node installer to install Node.js and with it the npm (node package manager).

Comment: Hitting F5 just launches whatever task you've configured. It won't necessarily compile and launch a C# application